# 404 (Not Found) while trying to access single post with Vue 3 and Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a small app in Vue 3 which I list data from a local json file and then click over to a detail page to view the rest of the data.  I am able to list all the data and link to a detail page, but I cannot seem to figure out how to show the data of just the single id.

`router/index.js`

```js
...
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Ndas',
      component: Ndas
    },
    {
      path: '/nda/:id',
      name: 'NdaDetails',
      component: NdaDetails,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
...
```

`views/Ndas.vue` -- This Works

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>NDAS</h1>
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-for="nda in ndas" :key="nda.id">

      <router-link :to="{ name: 'NdaDetails', params: { id: nda.id }}">
        <h2>{{ nda.user_signature }}</h2>
      </router-link>

    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      ndas: []
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.loading = true;
    axios
        .get('../../data/data.json')
        .then(response => (this.ndas = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)

  },
}
</script>
```

`views/NdaDetails.vue` -- This Doesn't Work

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="nda">
      <h1>NDA's Detail Page</h1>
      <p>The job title is {{ nda.user_signature }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data() {
    return {
      nda: {}
    }
  },

  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('../../data/data.json/'+this.id);
      this.nda = res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I meant to update this thread.  It was the most obvious thing I missed.  Since I was pulling the json file locally, it worked when outputting the entire list, but when I needed to view a single record by `id`, the json file needed to be served from a server so I could access `/data/12`, which is why it worked when testing with `json server`.  It was one of your suggestions that lit the lightbulb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: OP fixed the issue by serving his JSON file with a server, now it's working great.

---

Here, you probably want something like this rather than a prop

```js
const res = await axios.get('../../data/data.json/' + this.$route.params.id)
```

Props are used in a child/parent content, to pass some state down.
Here, you can access the value of your URL directly (router being global) and remove the `props` part.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  Actually, I just realized the console shows the name of the json file in the route and not just the id.

Comment: @CharlesSmith where is your file actually located? Maybe `/data/12.json`?

Comment: in a root directory called data--in a file name data.json

Comment: @CharlesSmith how do you expect to get the `12` of it so? There is no such resource. You can only `.find` on the array I guess.